# XML - how to get namespace tag name?

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("URL");

$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
```

i'm getting the namespaces for like this

```
Array
(
    [aaa] => http://www.aaa.com/rss/module/save/1.0.2
    [dc] => http://bbb.org/dc/elements/1.1/
)
```

i need the name for (aaa,dc)

How to get the namespaces name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("URL");

$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);

// loop through the namespaces and echo them out
foreach($namespaces as $name => $value)
{
    echo 'namespace: ' . $name;
}
```

Comment: They have asked for the **tag** name containing the namespace declaration. You're just printing namespace names.

Comment: @Leigh Actually no, they have asked for the tag name as a string which is what I gave.

Comment: @MrCode: It very clearly states "How to get the namespaces Tag name?". If your answer is what they required then the question is terribly worded. In `<tagname xmlns:t="http://t.org/ns">` "tagname" is the **tag name**